# Why does pinning a UIStackView on all edges cause an ambiguous constraint Error?

Tags: swift, autolayout, uikit, constraints, uistackview

The following code is an attempt to programatically pin a UIStackView on all edges - ie make it full screen. What is it about these seemingly simple constraints that cause this error?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [])

        view.addSubview(stack)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
```

}

Constraint error printed in debugger (link to [WTFAutoLayout](https://www.wtfautolayout.com/?constraintlog=(%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600003407840%20h%3D--%26%20v%3D--%26%20UIStackView:0x7f97e240f020.width%20%3D%3D%200%20%20%20(active)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x60000340ccd0%20H:%7C-(0)-%5BUIStackView:0x7f97e240f020%5D%20%20%20(active,%20names:%20%27%7C%27:UIView:0x7f97e6002d90%20)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x60000340dd10%20UIStackView:0x7f97e240f020.trailing%20%3D%3D%20UIView:0x7f97e6002d90.trailing%20%20%20(active)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x6000034073e0%20%27UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width%27%20UIView:0x7f97e6002d90.width%20%3D%3D%20414%20%20%20(active)%3E%22%0A))):

```
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600003407840 h=--& v=--& UIStackView:0x7f97e240f020.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000340ccd0 H:|-(0)-[UIStackView:0x7f97e240f020]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f97e6002d90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000340dd10 UIStackView:0x7f97e240f020.trailing == UIView:0x7f97e6002d90.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000034073e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x7f97e6002d90.width == 414   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000340dd10 UIStackView:0x7f97e240f020.trailing == UIView:0x7f97e6002d90.trailing   (active)>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below code as well,

```
stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Comment: Ah I feel silly. 
I was working on a more complex example and in the process of simplifying the code in order to post this question I have accidentally removed that line and ended up asking the wrong question! ‍♂️